# Sonar coverage angular unit test not covered

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, sonarqube

Here's my method inside the typescript file

```
  public get(url: any, options?: object): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url.path, merge(options, { params: { metaData: url } }))
      .pipe(map((response) => response));
  }
```

And following is the unit test case written in Angular8

```
it('Should call get method', fakeAsync(() => {
    service.get(apiUrl, {}).subscribe(response => response);
    const req = httpTestingController.match(reqObj => {
      return reqObj.url === apiUrl.path;
    });
    expect(req[0].request.method).toBe('GET');
  }));
```

The Sonar coverage says the response variable inside .pipe(map) is not being covered.

```
public get(url: any, options?: object): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url.path, merge(options, { params: { metaData: url } }))
      .pipe(map(**(response) => response)**);
  }
```

Any ideas on covering the whole method. Or a better Unit test case for this method. Thanks in advance!

Comment: your test calls service.post method and sonar coverage shows you that the get method is not tested.

Comment: Something else is to remove `map((response) => response)`. It is doing nothing.

Comment: @OLO I have edited that was a typo mistake.